# Changing the image of a CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created a number of CCSprites using spriteWithFile.

How do I change the image for the sprite during runtime?

I need to change a few sprites images quite regularly.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
CCTexture *tex = [CCTexture textureWithFile:fileName];
self.texture = tex;
```

Comment: what to do if texture is different in size from previous one ?

Comment: @FaheemRajput.. If the sprites are of different size then you will need to do this after calling setTexture function --- [spriteWant2Change setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, tex.contentSize.width, tex.contentSize.height)];---

Comment: Anyone knows how to do this in cocos2d 3.x ? Because xcode doesn't find CCTextureCache anymore.

Comment: is one cctexture  on another Cctexture overlap it or remove it from cache ?? what exactly happens we setTexture ?

Comment: @PaxMaximinus you can do so by 
aSprite.texture = [[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"steelDemonNormal.png"] texture];

Answer (score 14):

If you are using SpriteSheets, this will work.

```
NSString* newSprite = [NSString stringWithString:@"SPRITE_NAME.png"];
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
[sprite setDisplayFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:newSprite]];
```

Comment: If not using SpriteSheets , than what should I do?

Answer (score 9):

```
[yourSprite setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"yourImage.png"]texture]];
```

Comment: Cocos2d v3 would be:

[yourSprite setTexture:[[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:filename]texture]];

Answer (score 4):

In COCOS2D-X you can do this by following way

```
CCTexture2D *tex = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("xyz.png");
sprit_name->setTexture(tex);
```

iF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE SPRITE SIZE THEN ALSO WRITE THIS LINE

```
sprit_name->setTextureRect(CCRectMake(0,0, tex->getContentSize().width, tex->getContentSize().height));
```

Answer (score 1):

i code cocos2D-x in c++ :
when you use spriteSheet instead of using single file, you shoud use this method.
suppose you add your spriteSheet in main layer.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("sprite_sheet.plist");
_gameBatchNode = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("sprite_sheet.png", 200);
this->addChild(_gameBatchNode, kMiddleground);
```

kMiddleground is just a defined integer.

then i want to change picture of a sprite that already has a sprite with name "cloud.png"
i use this code to do that:

```
cloud->setDisplayFrame(CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName("blackCloud.png") );
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Cocos2d-iPhone v 3.0.0 or later

```
demonSprite.texture = [[CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"steelDemonNormal.png"] texture];
```

Answer (score 0):

if You are using SpriteSheets then this will work

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batch;
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFrameWithFile:@"file.plist"];

batch = [[[CCSpriteBatchNode alloc] initWithFile:@"file.png"] capacity:50] autorelease];

[self addChild:batch];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using atlassed textures for you game because you are using same sprite that too with many instances

Use

> CCSpriteFrameCache, CCSpriteBatchNode

So you can optimize the texture cache with even more different textures atlassed in a single texture. And all are batched in a single node. This reduces the number of draw calls too and increases frame rate.

Try using

```
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Characters.plist"];

    CCSpriteBatchNode* batch = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"Characters.png" capacity:10];
    [self addChild:batch];

    CCSprite* player1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"Luce.png"];
    player1.position = ccp(winSize.width * 0.2, winSize.height * 0.8);
    [batch addChild:player1];
```

and use

```
        CCSprite* player = nil;
    CCARRAY_FOREACH(batch.children, player1) {
        // some computational code and condition
        if (sonecondition) {
            [player1 setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"spriteframename.png"]];
        }
    }
```

in update or in other parts of code

Use [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/%E2%80%8E)

[TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to create 2D texture atlasses

Hope this helps

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the images continuously then write following code in your init method

`CCTexture2D *tex1 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image1.png"];
CCTexture2D *tex2 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image2.png"];
CCTexture2D *tex3 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image3.png"];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex1];
//Make above variables as class level to access in whole class
[self addChild:sprite];
//position the sprite according to your need`

write this line where you want to change the image

`[sprite setTexture:tex3];`

Answer (score 0):

you need to make one cctexture2d object in such a way

CCTexture2D* newtexture = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"new-texture"];
[mainSprite setTexture: newtexture];

this is a whole thing needed to be done if you want change sprite image texture run time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the texture of your CCSprite at runtime like this.

```
[aSprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"NewImage.png"]];
```