# Can We change the players images dynamically in cocos2d game?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I want to select the player image from gallery or I can take picture from cam and I need to animate those images while player movement. I am new to cocos2d, can any body help me ?

Comment: [playerSprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"playerWithShield.png"]];

Comment: I need to take the picture dynamically and that should be applied to players image

Comment: [playerSprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringwithformat@"%@",yourimage]]]];

Comment: Thanks man,but at a time i need to show 3-4 animations while player moving....

Comment: u can use nstimer to achieve that problem @Raj

Comment: actually in my game i need to take picture from cam for player and than u need to animate that picture for players images dynamically in cocos2d game

Comment: sorry dear...i don't have much knowledge in cocos2d game @Raj.......

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896075/changing-the-image-of-a-ccsprite

Comment: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_sprite.html#ae41c556a12991defd766670eae6ba700

Answer (score 0):

To change player animations, you need to run a `CCAnimate` action on it.

```
// Add sprite frames to sprite frame cache (if you are using a spritesheet)
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"NinjaPreto.plist"];

// Create animation
CCAnimation* animation = [CCAnimation animation];

// Create sprite frames
CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame1 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"animation1.png"];
CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame2 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"animation2.png"];
CCSpriteFrame *spriteFrame3 = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"animation3.png"];

// Add sprite frames to animation
[animation addSpriteFrame:spriteFrame1];
[animation addSpriteFrame:spriteFrame2];
[animation addSpriteFrame:spriteFrame3];

animation.delayPerUnit = 0.1;
animation.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;

// Run action
[player runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animation]];
```

So, if you want to change the player image, just create a new animation action with the new images that you want.

PS.: If you just want to change player image, without animation, use:

```
[player setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"image.png"]];
```

Comment: Take a look at Apple documentation. It also have examples: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010405-SW1

Answer (score 0):

In COCOS2D-X you can do this by following way

```
CCTexture2D *tex = CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("xyz.png");
sprit_name->setTexture(tex);
```

iF YOU WANT TO CHANGE THE SPRITE SIZE THEN ALSO WRITE THIS LINE

```
sprit_name->setTextureRect(CCRectMake(0,0, tex->getContentSize().width, tex->getContentSize().height));
```